# How do I display multiple many-to-many relationship data on a single page in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am creating a blog application and have a many to many relationship between posts and categories. I have my relationships correctly set up, and to view all the categories for one particular post, I run the following code in the PostController:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    $relatedCategories = Post::find($id)->categories()->get();

    return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post)->with('relatedCategories', $relatedCategories);
}
```

The above code works for a page showing data about one individual post. On the other hand, I have the main page meant to display all the available posts, each post in a table row, and all the categories for each post in a column in the table. To grab all the data for the available posts, I use the following code:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

    return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

However, I'm unsure how to pass on the data for the categories each post belongs to via the controller because the obvious solution of querying for each post's categories is not possible in the view section. How do I properly configure the controller file's code to send the correct data for categories to display for each individual row of post? Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Post model, you can override the toArray() method, and make it returns what you want :

```
return [ 
  'id' => $this->id,
  'relatedCategories' => $this->categories
];
```

or you can make this query :

```
$posts = Post::with('categories')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```